# Using FontAwesome with AngularJS and Gulp

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sass, gulp, font-awesome

I am currently using a setup with **NO Bower** and **ONLY** using **NPM** with Gulp for AngularJS. I installed [Font-Awesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome) from npm. I am also using SASS/SCSS for this.

The stylesheet is already loaded whenever i would run `gulp serve` as I have checked it using the developers tools in chrome, but the fonts are not loaded with it as I am outputted with a 404 when loading the font-awesome fonts.

I used the `$fa-font-path` variable with it. I imported it using:

```
$fa-font-path: "node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/";
@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

[Bootstrap-Sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-sass) is working fine and loading its font values using `$icon-font-path` despite of the fonts not being in the folder being served using:

```
$icon-font-path: "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

I've tried importing it using [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome) and it is fully working, but I do **NOT** want to use the CDN as an exception for this as I am using NPM for all my dependencies with this.

So, why is font-awesome not working? Am I doing something wrong with my setup?

Comment: I had the same issue with another lib, please make sure you are not wrong with the path check folder names and path you are giving on are the same. 404 error mean that can't find what you are trying to load

Comment: @SiderTopalov That's why I am asking here. Yes 404 means invalid path, that's why I am asking for the correct setup here in case I am doing something wrong with mine. :)

Comment: @SiderTopalov I found `$fa-font-path` in `_variables.scss` file inside font-awesome in node_modules. So since the default one (without overriding it) did not work (which was `../font`), i tried changing it to `node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/` like what i did in my bootstrap-sass as it is working for bootstrap. But sadly, it did not work for font-awesome. Still having a 404 message for it.